# What are all the different classes of functions upon real numbers and what do they mean, exactly?

Tags: functions, terminology

I have been hearing terms like "piecewise C1", "continuous", "linear", "piecewise constant", "trigonometric", "logarithmic", "exponential", "elementary", etc. functions for many years.

I know what most of those terms mean (I do not know the meaning of the first one).

However, what are the major branches of functions, and what do they mean? I don't expect people to list all of the minor one's or the one's that everyone study up through basic calculus, mind you. That would be incredibly excessive. I am more interested in the large subsets relating to continuity and calculus.

However, referring to all function branches: Are they all references to the sort of graphs they give or are there special classes based upon other kinds of properties such as recursive definitions?

The idea is what *do* the types mean. Sometimes they seem to refer to the functions used to define and express them. Other times it seems to be abstract graphical concepts?

Are there certain branches of types of functions? How do they all connect in terms of classification? This part of the question does not neccessarily have to be answered, but if one can it would be very nice in a visual sort of way of connecting things together...

**Note:** Just so people are aware, I know what the definition of a function is. This question is about how they are *classified*, and what properties are looked at and used when classifying.

Comment: I like this question because I like classifying things. However, I have to imagine that a complete answer to your question would be impossibly long -- there are just about as many different kinds of functions as there are kinds of sets, if not more. Classifications are possible more or less in the context of specific fields, but if you don't narrow down your question, it is unlikely you will get any answer you find satisfying

Comment: My suggestion would be to ask about the different types/levels of continuous/differentiable functions from the real numbers to the real numbers, since that seems most similar to your question based on some of the examples given.

Comment: One can probably ask a sensible question along this line, but asking us to list all classes of real functions is not one.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Thats why i said classes of classes of real numbers. Like are there ones that go hand in hand with the piecewise c one? I might be able to edit it more narrowed if I knew what that meant. Perhaps ask about different numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f \in C^1$ then it has continuous partial derivatives. Roughly, if $f$ is piecewise $C^1$, then $f:\bigcup X_{i} \rightarrow \bigcup Y_{1}$ is a piecewise function s.t. $f|_{X_{i}} \in C^1.$

Comment: $f|_{X_{I}}$ is the restriction of $f$ to the subset $X_{i}$.

Comment: Oh I see. So each subset would be the piecewise sections of the function that would individually be in c1?

Comment: Yes exactly what I mean.

Comment: Would you be willing to explain what the 1 in c^1 means? I get a feeling there are levels to these, but I am not sure what that entails other than possibly complex numbers.

Comment: A $C^n$ function is an $n$-times differentiable function with a continuous $n$-th derivative. BTW, from what I've seen, usually by "piecewise" we mean "(continuous, continuously differentiable, etc.) except on a finite number of points" (as this almost exclusively refer to functions defined on intervals of $\mathbb{R}$).